# How to apply matlab logical filter to select constant dataset

Tags: matlab, filter

I need to use logical filter to select certain period in a long data set but I want to ignore initial period of filtered data. For example we have two column vector ('A' and 'B') as follows.

A =

```
10
 5
 6
 6
10
 2
 3
 2
 1
 3
 2
 3
 3
 7
 9
 8
 6
 8
 8
12
```

B =

```
10
 5
 6
 6
 2
 2
 3
 2
 1
 3
 2
 3
 3
 7
 9
 8
 6
 8
 8
12
```

Now I can create a filter based on column 'B' to select certain period in column  'A'

```
 logicalFilter = B<=3 & B>1;
```

A(logicalFilter)

ans =

```
10
 2
 3
 2
 3
 2
 3
 3
```

Now I need to ignor lets say first five data point in 'A(logicalFilter)' and take the average of remaining. 
How it can be done?

Second option would be that I do not ignore first fix data points but only select a period in 'A(logicalFilter)' where the number are constant to calculate average. How is it possible?

As it has been suggest to expand my question further to take averages over different blocks in a continues dataset. Again we have two columns ('A' and 'B') as follows.
A =

```
10
 5
 6
 6
10
 2
 3
 2
 1
 3
 2
 3
 3
 7
 9
 8
 6
 8
 8
12
```

B =

```
10
 5
 6
 6
 2
 2
 3
 2
 1
 3
 2
 3
 3
 7
 2
 2
 3
 3
 8
12

logicalFilter = B<=3 & B>1
```

logicalFilter =

```
 0
 0
 0
 0
 1
 1
 1
 1
 0
 1
 1
 1
 1
 0
 1
 1
 1
 1
 0
 0
```

Now I need to take averages of 'A' corresponding to 'logicalFilter'=1 for different blocks of 'logicalFilter'=1 separately and also ignoring first two points (for example) 'logicalFilter'=1 for the calculation of averages.

Comment: Well, simply assign to a temporary variable: `Atmp=A(logicalFilter); mean(Atmp(6:end))` will ignore the first 5 elements after filtering. But what do you exactly mean by "selecting a period where the number are constant"?

Comment: @Adras Deak: should not vary alot. May be a limit can be applied like to consider those data points only for avg. calculations where the point to point variability is not more than 5%.

Comment: This reminds me of an [xkcd strip](http://xkcd.com/1425/). Dropping the first five elements is trivial. Determining which part of a dataset "is roughly constant" is a whole different league:) So if you're content with the first, than go with it. You could check for instance `diff(Atmp)./Atmp(1:end-1)<=0.05` and use this new logical filter to again filter your data. But things like this can get messy and can give unexpected results if your data set is not exactly what you expected. Note that your example data varies 50% point to point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip the first `N` data points after filtering by assigning to a temporary variable:

```
N = 5; %number of points to skip after filtering

logicalFilter = B<=3 & B>1;
Atmp = A(logicalFilter);
avg = mean(Atmp(N+1:end));
```

Choosing the points to average dynamically, based on their variance, is much trickier, and I'm not sure there's an elegant way to do so, and you need to think of a proper algorithm. For instance, your example in a comment by considering point-to-point variability would look like this:

```
%relative point-to-point difference to keep
q=0.05;

logicalFilter = B<=3 & B>1;
Atmp = A(logicalFilter);

varianceFilter = abs(diff(Atmp))./Atmp(1:end-1)<0.05;
avg = mean(Atmp(varianceFilter));
```

And this will average those points from `Atmp(1:end-1)` which don't differ from the following data point by more than a relative error of `q=0.05`.

But note that for your example data you will get only 1 point which is the same as the next one up to an error of 5%, since you have integers and only neighbouring identical integers will qualify for your filter.

**Update**:
Another approach is much more computationally demanding, but it seems a proper way to go. You should find the first index from which the data in `Atmp` are weakly scattered, i.e. their standard deviation is small. This assumes, of course, that after a given point your deviation is indeed small, otherwise you will loop over your whole vector and keep the last point. Here's what I mean:

```
%relative standard deviation to keep
q=0.05;

logicalFilter = B<=3 & B>1;
Atmp = A(logicalFilter);

%worst case scenario
avg = Atmp(end);
for i=1:length(Atmp)-1
   if std(Atmp(i:end))<q
      avg = mean(Atmp(i:end));
      break;
   end
end
```

This will find the smallest `i` for which `Atmp(i:end)` has standard deviation less than `q`, compute the mean of this dataset, then stop working altogether.

---

**Update 2** regarding your edit:

> Now I need to take averages of 'A' corresponding to 'logicalFilter'=1 for different blocks of 'logicalFilter'=1 separately and also ignoring first two points (for example) 'logicalFilter'=1 for the calculation of averages.

We can adapt an answer [to a similar question at MATLAB Answers](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/77647#answer_87323):

```
aboveThreshold = logicalFilter;  %where above threshold
%aboveThreshold is a logical array, where 1 when above threshold, 0, below.
%we thus want to calculate the difference between rising and falling edges
aboveThreshold = [false; aboveThreshold; false];  %pad with 0's at ends
edges = diff(aboveThreshold);
startPos = find(edges==1);     %rising/falling edges
endPos = find(edges==-1)-1;

%at this point startPos and endPos contain the indices of each 'island'

%if you want to throw away islands shorter than 2 (inclusive):
needInds = endPos-startPos>1;
startPos = startPos(needInds);
endPos = endPos(needInds);

%now loop over each island and compute the mean
meanVec = zeros(length(startPos),1);
for i=1:length(startPos)
   Atmp = A(startPos(i):endPos(i));
   meanVec(i) = mean(Atmp(3:end));
end
```

Now `meanVec` is a vector containing the average of each data "island", with the first two points thrown away in each island (and correspondingly islands of at most 2 elements are thrown away).

Comment: How your lines work regarding skipping first 5 data points works? if there is repetition of filter criteria for different periods with a gap based on time.

Comment: @Umar, you just skip the first 5 data points *after* filtering, whatever those are. You could do this after every filtering step...

Comment: For example if the logical filter is as following.
logical filter
      1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
so now at  filter =1, the average value for data is required to calculate by ignoring first five 1.

Comment: I mean to say do I need here a for loop as I am only getting one average for the whole periods of 1 while I required  averages for the periods before 0 and after 0 when filter is 1 (in above case).

Comment: @Umar Note that requiring *separate* averages for each block of "equivalent" data is not at all part of your original problem specification. Where you average according to a filter based on `B` you lose such information unless you make extra steps. Consider expanding your question, then I (and probably others) will see what I (we) can do about it.

Comment: I expanded the question as you suggested. Thanks